# how to compare two calendar objects?

Tags: java, datetime, time, calendar

I want to compare two date objects like this:

```
    String format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    fakeDate = sdf.parse("15/07/2013 11:00 AM");
    fakeDate2 = sdf.parse("15/07/2013 12:00 AM");

int diff = date2.getHours() - date1.getHours();
```

but then I see getHours is deprecated.

So i have used:

```
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(new Date("15/7/2013 11:00AM"));
    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(new Date("11/7/2013 12:00AM"));

calendar1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) - calendar2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
```

but then I see the diff is zero. I guess i change the same calendar instance all the time and compare it to itself. no?

how would you write this?

Comment: Do you want to compare two `Date` objects, or two strings? It's very unclear what you're actually trying to do. Where does your data come from? What time zone is it in?

Comment: @JonSkeet want the difference between hours of two dates as per the code

Comment: @user3218114: That didn't answer any of my questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date("15/7/2013 11:00AM")
```

is not the correct way to construct a Date object. It's **deprecated** also. Use proper `SimpleDateFormat` as you are doing well in your first example.

The format `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a` is not correct as per the input date string.

It should be like this.

```
String format = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
Date fakeDate = sdf.parse("15/07/2013 11:00 AM");
Date fakeDate2 = sdf.parse("15/07/2013 12:00 AM");

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

cal.setTime(fakeDate); //set time to first date
int hours1 = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR); // get the hours

cal.setTime(fakeDate2); // set time to second date
int hours2 = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR); // get the hours

System.out.println(hours1 - hours2); // 11 hours
```

Comment: I see the diff is zero. I guess i change the same calendar instance all the time and compare it to itself. no?

Comment: There is difference of 11 hours.

Comment: you can use same instance of Calendar class. Just set the time and use it.

Comment: can you look at my code? my second assignment to calendar2 overriders calendar1 ?

Comment: As per your code there are three Calendar instance `calendar1` ,`calendar2` and `calendar` and `new Date("15/7/2013 11:00AM")` is not the correct way to construct the date object.

Comment: It should be `new Date(15/7/2013 11:00 AM)` but never suggest you to use it.

Comment: but then the difference between 23:00 to 09:00 is  14 hours and not 10

Comment: Have you tried my code? share `AM/PM` as well It got 14 with my code.

Comment: right but I want the difference to be 10 hours. cyclic diff

Comment: The format `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a` is not correct as per the input date string. It should be `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a`

Answer (score 0):

You seemed really confused though it is depreciated this code shall give you a difference of 11 hours which makes sense

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
    Date fakeDate = dateFormat.parse("15/07/2013 11:00 AM");
    Date fakeDate2 = dateFormat.parse("15/07/2013 12:00 AM");
    System.out.println(fakeDate.getHours()-fakeDate2.getHours());
```

Or if you are so interested to use Calendar do it this way

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(fakeDate);
    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar2.setTime(fakeDate2);
    System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) - 
                                 calendar2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
```

You will get the same 11 hours difference or simply do it this way

```
long millisForNewDate = toDate.getTime();
long millisForOldDate = fromDate.getTime();
long difference = millisForNewDate - millisForOldDate;
int hoursDifferenceBetweenDates = (int)(difference/(1000*60*60));
```

Comment: Look at my post.  `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a` format not matched as input date string.